# Connection error in java website. Tnsping shows that the service is running

Tags: jakarta-ee, connection-pooling, runtime-error, tnsnames

I have a java website application running in windows 7 which uses oracle database for its functionalities. The database has default SID name orcl. When I use tnsping, I can see that the orcl service is active. Also most of the application is working fine except for one part. I was wondering if someone could help me with the following error:-

```
1. cause:

message:null,java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.olat.course.statistic.StatisticAutoCreator.createController(StatisticAutoCreator.java:73)
at org.olat.course.statistic.StatisticActionExtension.createController(StatisticActionExtension.java:40)
at org.olat.course.statistic.StatisticMainController.createController(StatisticMainController.java:80)
at org.olat.core.gui.control.generic.layout.GenericMainController.getContentCtr(GenericMainController.java:258)
at org.olat.core.gui.control.generic.layout.GenericMainController.event(GenericMainController.java:221)
at org.olat.core.gui.control.DefaultController.dispatchEvent(DefaultController.java:196)

2. cause:

message:Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection,org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException

at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:381)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:455)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:463)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:471)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:476)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForLong(JdbcTemplate.java:480)
at org.olat.course.statistic.SimpleStatisticInfoHelper.doGetFirstLoggingTableCreationDate(SimpleStatisticInfoHelper.java:63)
at org.olat.course.statistic.SimpleStatisticInfoHelper.getFirstLoggingTableCreationDate(SimpleStatisticInfoHelper.java:81)
at org.olat.course.statistic.StatisticDisplayController.getStatsSinceStr(StatisticDisplayController.java:517)

3. cause:

message:The Network Adapter could not establish the connection,java.sql.SQLException

at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:203)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)

4. cause:

message:The Network Adapter could not establish the connection,oracle.net.ns.NetException

at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:328)
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:421)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:634)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:203)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)

5. cause:

message:Connection timed out: connect,java.net.ConnectException

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:372)
at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:186)
at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:127)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement Oracle specific templates in /src/main/java/org/olat/course/statistic/_spring/statisticContext.xml? This is a bit specific as the logging infrastructure has some database vendor specific elements.

Note that Oracle is not officially supported in OLAT nor in OpenOLAT. There are other known issues when using Oracle such as the NULL value handling. MySQL and Oracle have different philosophies here. Those issues can not be addressed in the hibernate layer, you have to test the entire application and make code changes.

If you are working with OpenOLAT (http://www.openolat.org) and are willing to contribute the Oracle compatibility adjustments, please subscribe to the OpenOLAT mailinglist and send us your patches.

Cheers
Florian